# Firebase admin SDK Java: No user record found for the provided email

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to get the user id of the user through email at the backend. The code I'm using is this.

```
val user:UserRecord?
try {
  user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUserByEmail(email)
}catch(e:Exception){
  map["msg"]=e.localizedMessage
  return map
    }

map["msg"]=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomTokenAsync(user.uid).get()
return map
```

Line 3 produces an exception.

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: No user record found for the 
provided email: id
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUserManager.getUserByEmail(FirebaseUserManager.java:138)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$7.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:613)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$7.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:610)
at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getUserByEmail(FirebaseAuth.java:590)
at in.ac.krishnacollege.CheckTeacherResource.checkTeacherEmail(CheckTeacherResource.kt:27)
```

The function getUserByEmail() should return null but it throws an exception.

Comment: "If the provided email does not belong to an existing user or the user cannot be fetched for any other reason, the Admin SDK throws an error." https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data

Comment: Sounds like an answer @jdv! :-)

Comment: @jdv They should have made it return a null if the user is not found

Comment: @varunsharma you need to read the docs. It clearly says _otherwise_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not expert with Firebase. (I literally dropped "Firebase getUserByEmail" into a web search.) But a cursory reading of the [Firebase Guide for managing users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) has this to say about `getUserByEmail(email)`:

> This method returns a UserRecord object for the user corresponding to
>   the email provided.
>
> If the provided email does not belong to an existing user or the user
>   cannot be fetched for any other reason, the Admin SDK throws an error.
>   For a full list of error codes, including descriptions and resolution
>   steps, see [Admin Authentication API
>   Errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors).

There is *no* mention of returning null for any of the user lookup methods described. All examples show error handling in a `catch` block (at least for the Javascript examples), *not* null handling. At least for the version and release describe here.

There are no Kotlin examples. The Java example does not show exception handling, but it does not change the explanation of how errors are to be handled, and you are clearly seeing the error exception in your own code.

There may be circumstances under which this method returns null under a JVM language, but that is not the case here.